# in a group of check boxes only allow one to be selected at a time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I want a group of check boxes on a page, when you select a check box I want to clear any other check boxes of checks and just check the one you just clicked on.  I have a fiddle that I thought should work, but it never checks the one you clicked on.  I don't want to use radio buttons as "no selection" is valid as well

```
$("#mytable input").change(function(){
$("#mytable input").attr('checked',false);
    $(this).attr('checked',true);
})
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/421m21zj/)

Comment: Maybe radio buttons would be more natural?

Comment: `radio` inputs works the same.

Comment: You're using `.attr` when you should be using `.prop`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should rather use radio button with same name. using checkboxes, you need to use:

```
$("#mytable input").change(function() {
 $("#mytable input").not(this).prop('checked', false);  
});
```

**[Working Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/hb5vhcy3/)**